# ffmpeg time-lapse input list of image file paths

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I would like to input a text file into ffmpeg that contain paths to every image i want for time-lapse. Is this possible and how? Thing is, my images are sorted into directories named by the current day and every image have timestamp, and some time images can come from different source and have for example incremental naming instead of timestamp, so i found best way to print a list of working directories into one text document.

Comment: This has an answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30188897/1487413